# Multiple CiviHR installation in single Amazon AWS instance

Tags: civihr

I have installed multiple CiviHR on Amazon AWS.

And configured VirtualHost as given below. so I can use the same domain and demo1 and demo 2 as a subdomain of it.

[image]

Both CiviHR installation was successful but in domain.com/demo/hr-details I'm not able to see any data that I have added. It displaying blank.

[image]

If I click on edit my details button I'm able to see the data I have added.

[image]

Highlighted URLs redirecting to root folder of the server (domain.com/dashboard instead of domain.com/demo1/dashboard).

Is this issue with VirtualHost configuration or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's purely apache/httpd configuration issue. Create 2 subdomain demo1.domain.com and demo2.domain.com and have 2 conf file under sites-available and sites-enabled with following config

demo1.domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/demo1

  ServerName demo1.domain.com

  ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

  <Directory "/var/www/html/demo1">

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted

    Options -Indexes

  </Directory>

  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/demo1.domain.com.error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,

  # alert, emerg.

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog  /var/log/apache2/demo1.domain.com.access.log  combined

</VirtualHost>
```

demo2.domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/demo2

  ServerName demo2.domain.com

  ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

  <Directory "/var/www/html/demo2">

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted

    Options -Indexes

  </Directory>

  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/demo2.domain.com.error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,

  # alert, emerg.

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog  /var/log/apache2/demo2.domain.com.access.log  combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It worked, now two subdomains pointed to two separate directories but the issue I have mentioned still persist.  Errors are like: (Angular) Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://domain.com/demo1/sites/all/modules/civicrm/tools/extensions/civihr/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.hrleaveandabsences/views/my-leave/components/my-leave-container.html and in console I can see net::ERR_ABORTED and Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).It automatically adding demo1 folder after subdomain name. eg: demo1.domain.com/demo1/sites/

Comment: Can you check base url in civicrm.settings.php is correct and also the path in directories and resource url are correct. Also try to delete template_c and clear civicrm cache.

Comment: Fixed. It was issue with base URL in civicrm.settings.php